# How we can differentiate that the emv data read from card chip is using Contact or contactless mode

Tags: contactless-smartcard, emv

I am reading card data for contact or contactless mode perfectly, but my query is how I can identify that is the card chip data is read using contactless mode or contact. It would be great If someone guide me about specific emv tag or other way to identify this difference for MPOS solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking as a terminal you know from the processing that the card is processed on a contact or a contactless interface. If you are looking as an acquirer or payment scheme or as a card issuer, De22( pos entry code ) will tell you the mode, the transaction was acquired.

There are no specific tags for MPOS transactions, it is just like any other POS transaction. As an acquirer you will have details of the terminals and so you can identify whether the terminal is an MPOS or not.
When you send the transaction to MasterCard you set Data Element 60 Sub Element 10  to  9 to indicate that the transaction was acquired on an MPOS, on a Visa you would send DE 60 SE 1 to 9. For each payment scheme this may differ. Refer the specific interface manuals.